# ¿Como sumar columnas en datatable usando Footer callback si existe una etiqueta html (button) dentro del td?

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

Estoy sumando los valores de un datatable con la funcion **Footer callback** pero suma solo aquellos td sin ningun etiqueta html ,sin embargo los imprimo el td con un boton y la funcion **Footer callback** no me las reconoce y me arroja este resultado = **$NaN ( $NaN total)**, como lo puedo solucionarlo..

```js
-- -- --Codigo de Ajax Listado-- -- -- -- --
$(document).ready(function() {

  //alert( f.getDate() + "/" + (f.getMonth() +1) + "/" + f.getFullYear()  );
  table = $('#table').DataTable({

    "scrollX": true,
    "scrollY": "240px",
    "lengthMenu": [
      [5, 15, 25, 50, 100, -1],
      [5, 15, 25, 50, 100, "Todo"]
    ],
    "scrollCollapse": true,
    "processing": true, //Feature control the processing indicator.
    "serverSide": true, //Feature control DataTables' server-side processing mode.
    "order": [], //Initial no order.
    "language": {
      "lengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ registros por pagina",
      "zeroRecords": "No se encontraron resultados en su busqueda",
      "searchPlaceholder": "Buscar registros",
      "info": "Mostrando  de _START_ al _END_  de  _TOTAL_ registros",
      "infoEmpty": "No existen registros",
      "infoFiltered": "",
      "search": "Buscar:",
      "processing": "Procesando...:",
      "paginate": {
        "first": "Primero",
        "last": "Último",
        "next": "Siguiente",
        "previous": "Anterior"
      },
    },
    // Load data for the table's content from an Ajax source
    "ajax": {
      "url": "<?php echo base_url(); ?>planilla/ajax_list",
      "type": "POST"
    },
    //Set column definition initialisation properties.
    "columnDefs": [{
      "targets": [-1], //last column
      "orderable": false, //set not orderable
    }, ],
    "footerCallback": function(row, data, start, end, display) {
      var api = this.api(),
        data;
      // Remove the formatting to get integer data for summation
      var intVal = function(i) {
        return typeof i === 'string' ?
          i.replace(/[\$,]/g, '') * 1 :
          typeof i === 'number' ?
          i : 0;
      };

      // Total over all pages
      total = api
        .column(3)
        .data()
        .reduce(function(a, b) {
          return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
        }, 0);

      // Total over this page
      pageTotal = api
        .column(3, {
          page: 'current',
          currency: "USD"
        })
        .data()
        .reduce(function(a, b) {
          return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
        }, 0);

      // Update footer
      $(api.column(3).footer()).html(
        '$' + pageTotal + ' ( $' + total + ' total)'
      );
    }

  });

});
```

```html
-------Codigo de controlador ------- 
public function ajax_list() { 
  $list = $this->Planilla_model->get_datatables();
  $data = array(); 
  $no = $_POST['start'];
  foreach ($list as $traba) { 
    $originalDate1 = $traba->fechaInTraba;
    $newDate1 = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($originalDate1));
    $originalDate2 = $traba->fechaCese; 
    $newDate2 = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($originalDate2)); $originalDate3 = 
    $traba->fechaBoleta;
    $newDate3 = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($originalDate3));
    $no++;
    $row = array(); 
    $row[] = $no; 
    $row[] = '<button class="estilo" style="width: 100%; border:none; background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); padding:0; margin:0;  text-align: right;" onclick="vista(' . " '" . $traba->idPlanilla . "' " . ')">' . $traba->remuneracion . '</button>';
    $row[] = '<button class="estilo" style="width: 100%; border:none; background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); padding:0; margin:0;  text-align: right;"
      onclick="vista(' . " '" . $traba->idPlanilla . "' " . ')">' . $traba->totaldsctos . '</button>';
    $row[] = $traba->tnetopagar; 
    $row[] = '<button class="estilo" style="width: 100%; border:none; background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); padding:0; margin:0;  text-align: right;"
      onclick="vista(' . " '" . $traba->idPlanilla . "' " . ')">' . $traba->essalud . '</button>'; 
    $data[] = $row; 
  }
  $output = array( "draw" => $_POST['draw'], 
                   "recordsTotal" => $this->Planilla_model->count_all(), 
                   "recordsFiltered" => $this->Planilla_model->count_filtered(),
                   "data" => $data, ); //output to json format 
  echo json_encode($output); 
}
```

Comment: En tu codigo solo veo 5 columnas, porque tienes `.column(45, {`?

Comment: Bueno lo tengo como 50 columnas pero las corte para pegar un codigo pequeño

Comment: Hola resolvieron el Problemas ?  si es así, como lo hicieron.